# Чтение из входного потока конкретного количества обьектов в вектор

Tags: c++, stl

Известно, что можно читать из потока все данные следующим образом:

```
 vector<int> v;
 copy(istream_iterator<int>(stream), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(v));
```

Вопрос:  а как читать некое конкретное количество вводимых чисел, с целью записать остальные данные в другую последовательность? (Например из `cin` читать 3 числа в вектор, а следующие 3 в  `std::list<int> li`) Имеется ввиду с  помощью  STL алгоритма

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<int> a;
list<int>   b;

istringstream is("878 57 3 62 567 23 18 7 5 0");
copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(is),3, back_inserter(a));
copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(is),3, back_inserter(b));
```

Comment: Вы как всегда навысоте!..

Answer (score 1):

```
  generate_n(back_inserter(v), 3, [](){ int n; cin >> n; return n; });
    generate_n(back_inserter(li), 3, [](){ int n; cin >> n; return n; });
```

Comment: @Harry, вы дали идею на такое решение тоже

Comment: Да, пока не посмотрел в книгу и не увидел, чтО я написал... :)